# Best practice for counting polygons in polygons

Tags: postgis, polygon, postgresql, overlapping-features, count

I have two sets of polygons. One is representing populated areas and it contains about 30k of polygons. Other set contains smaller polygons.
I want to count how many smaller polygons are within populated areas.
I made a query and run it but it is running for 24 house now.
Second dataset is very large, about 120 million polygons.

```sql
select count(*) 
from public.pop_areas pa 
left join public.polys p
    on st_contains(pa.geom, p.wkb_geometry);
```

Is there any way to speed this up? Also, I have indices on geometry fields.

Comment: Index of the populated areas is probably not very selective because the areas are large. Large number of vertices in the geometries make also ST_Contains slow. ST_Subdivide should help with both issues https://postgis.net/docs/ST_Subdivide.html.

Comment: @user30184 subdividing does not really work well with *Polygon* containment. Gridding might, but then you'd be stuck with gridding 120 million *Polygons*...

Comment: Hmm, I noticed also that a small polygon can belong to several subdivided polygons of populated areas and ST_Contains would give wrong results. Pre-checking centroids against subdivided polygons might still get some benefit.

Comment: @user39184 yet it would require a second table to pre-filter, or a costly correlated/`LATERAL` subquery to then check for containment of a union by id or sth.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

True *Polygon* containment is a costly operation; not only does a containment check have to run intersection computations between each pair of vertices in one polygon *for each pair* of vertices in the other, but is it also impossible to improve by subdividing any of them.

That being said, your query is also not going to return the desired result; you are counting any non-containing *Polygon*s in `public.pop_areas`, plus one row for each of them containing one *Polygon* of `public.polys`; remove the `LEFT JOIN`, and `COUNT` only matching rows in `public.polys`:

```
SELECT COUNT(ply.*)
FROM   public.polys AS ply
JOIN   public.pop_places AS pop
  ON   pop.geom ~ ply.wkb_geometry 
WHERE  ST_Contains(pop.geom, ply.wkb_geometry)
;
```

The `~` condition may seem superfluous (it is implemented in `ST_Contains`), but might force a faster index lookup nonetheless.

---

Depending on the average shape of those *Polygon*s you may see a boost in performance when pre-filtering by the `ST_PointOnSurface` of your `public.polys.wkb_geometry`:

```
SELECT COUNT(ply.*)
FROM   public.polys AS ply
JOIN   public.pop_places AS pop
  ON   pop.geom ~ ply.wkb_geometry 
 AND   ST_Intersects(pop.geom, ST_PointOnSurface(ply.wkb_geometry))
WHERE  ST_Contains(pop.geom, ply.wkb_geometry)
;
```

The idea is to limit the containment check to only those *Polygon*s where at least the `ST_PointOnSurface` intersects the larger *Polygon*.

Comment: Second query took about 5 hours to calculate but it worked.  Please correct ST_Contains(ply.wkb_geometry, pop.geom) to ST_Contains(pop.geom, ply.wkb_geometry).

Comment: @DrJacoby corrected, thx.! 5h is nothing I would be surprised about. Note that `CREATE TABLE <name> AS SELECT ply.* FROM ... ;` might be significantly faster, and leaves you with lasting options for that data. Or an `UPDATE` on an added column (e.g. `isContained  BOOL`) even, though this would likely take about the same time.

Comment: This should use ST_PointOnSurface.  Polygon centroids do not always lie inside the polygon.

Comment: @dr_jts I used `ST_Centroid` on purpose, though, with my point being that its significantly lower complexity is adequate for a fast pre-filter, considering that this approach only ever really mskes sense for cases where the checked polygon is small enough to pass the bbox containment, but outside the actual bounds.

Comment: Good point.  ST_PointOnSurface is about as fast as ST_Centroid, though, so seems better to promote its use, even in this case.

Comment: @dr_jts did you guys improve it with 3.0?

Comment: Yes:  https://lin-ear-th-inking.blogspot.com/2019/02/better-and-faster-interior-point-for.html

Comment: @dr_jts about time ,) I saw the new algorithm in the JTS a while back, wondered when it would find its way to the derivates...well then, I shall edit the answer, and join your cause in spreading the word.